# Calculate Accuracy, Precison and Recall for Naive Bayes classifier (Manual Calculation)

Tags: r, precision, naivebayes

Being a new to R and NB classifier. I wold like  to confirm that my manual calculation for accuracy,Precision and Recall  is correct.I was also curious if there is any package available for this type of calculation.

For accuracy I used sum diag/total numbers of rows.

For precision I did diag/sum of rows

For recall I did diag/sum of column

```
> t<-CrossTable(test_pred1,test_labels, prop.chisq = T, prop.t = T, prop.r = FALSE,
+            dnn = c('predicted', 'actual'))


   Cell Contents
|-------------------------|
|                       N |
| Chi-square contribution |
|           N / Col Total |
|         N / Table Total |
|-------------------------|


Total Observations in Table:  31 


             | actual 
   predicted |         f |         t | Row Total | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
           f |         6 |        15 |        21 | 
             |     0.062 |     0.022 |           | 
             |     0.750 |     0.652 |           | 
             |     0.194 |     0.484 |           | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
           t |         2 |         8 |        10 | 
             |     0.131 |     0.045 |           | 
             |     0.250 |     0.348 |           | 
             |     0.065 |     0.258 |           | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
Column Total |         8 |        23 |        31 | 
             |     0.258 |     0.742 |           | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
```

**My manual calculation:**

```
> sum(diag(t$t))/sum(t$t) #Accuracy
[1] 0.4516129
> diag(t$t)/21 #Precision for F
        f         t 
0.2857143 0.3809524 
> diag(t$t)/10 #Precison for T
  f   t 
0.6 0.8 
> 
> diag(t$t)/8 #Recall for F
   f    t 
0.75 1.00 
> diag(t$t)/23 #Recall for T
        f         t 
0.2608696 0.3478261
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I wish someone answered your question completely, especially with regard to whether you did the calculations correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `confusionMatrix()` function in the `caret` package, here's an example:

```
require(caret)
confusionMatrix(test_pred1, test_labels)
```

This function needs two factor vectors of same length, the "predicted" and the "actual".
You can use `as.factor(test_pred1)` to force the factor type on your vectors.

See `?confusionMatrix` for more details. The output has all the metrics you need for a classification problem.